# Print keys and values in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the keys:

```
mykeys=["a", "b"]
mydictionary = { "a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 6}
```

I want to print out the key, value pair from my keys. Example output:

```
result = {"a": 1, "b": 3 }
```

When I use list comprehension I can only get the values:

```
  [mydictionary[x] for x in mykeys]
```

Comment: Use a dictionary comprehension: `{x: mydictionary[x] for x in mykeys}`

Comment: Look in the documentation about dictionaries and especially the `items()` methode

Comment: Thankk yoou!!!!